# setting a useState to true when the current value is already true causes re-render

Tags: reactjs, use-state

```
const [ready, set_ready] = useState(false);

...

if (condition === true) {
  set_ready(true);
}
```

The code above causes infinite loop.

But if I changed it to

```
if (condition === true && !ready) {
  set_ready(true);
}
```

The the problem is fixed.

This means that setting the `ready` useState to its current value triggers re-render.

This does not make sense.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: you should only use `set_**` inside another `use***`. like `useEffect(() => {}, []);`  so you only on mount

Comment: that was the problem, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a state setter is called, it does two things:

- Updates React's internal state for that state variable
- Re-renders the component. In functional components, this will call the component function again, and the various `useState` calls return the updated internal state.

So if you unconditionally call a state setter in the main body of a functional component, you'll be triggering a re-render every time the function runs - and a re-render will result in the function being called again, hence the infinite loop.

Putting the state setter call inside a condition ensures that it only gets called when it needs to, rather than on every single render.